# How to refine list of directories to remove subdirectories of newly added directory

Tags: python

I have a list of directories, eg:

```
direc_list = [r'C:\test', r'C:\test2\subdir']
```

I then want to add another directory to the list

```
new_direc = r'C:\test2'
```

How can I correctly remove any subdirectories of this new directory in my list?

After adding `r'C:\test2'` my output should be so that

```
direc_list
>>> [r'C:\test', r'C:\test2']
```

I was trying this using the `in` operator,

```
for direc in direc_list:        
    if new_direc in direc:
        direc_list.remove(direc)
```

but this fails because the word 'test' is a substring of 'test2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simply add an path seperator after the path.

```
import os
for direc in direc_list:        
    if direc.startswith(new_direc + os.sep):
        dir_list.remove(direc)
```

Comment: Thanks. Using os.sep is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use str.startswith() as in:

```
for direc in direc_list:
    if direc.startswith(new_direc):
        dir_list.remove(direc)
```

Depending upon input, might want to check out something like, os.path.abspath(path) to normalize your paths so they match up better.